# Is is possible to attach a new ELB into an existing ASG via cloudformation update?

Tags: amazon-elb, amazon-cloudformation

I would like to know if there is a way to update the ASG definition during cloudformation creation itself to have an additional Load balancer.

Something similar to what we have for updating Security group using       "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress".

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, until a while ago. Since January 17th, 2017 the answer is yes (see [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html)). The [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-loadbalancernames) has since been updated.

Before that, it was not possible to replace the attribute LoadBalancerNames without replacing the Auto Scaling Group.

I like to believe that this was due to me requesting that feature a while ago, but who knows.

Of course, this only applies to Auto Scaling Groups created with CloudFormation. For all other Auto Scaling Groups the answer is a definitive 'no'.